# Is there anyway to retrieve direct parent of a child item in JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm creating a simple REST server using Spring framework.
One of the class needs to have a self join one to many relationship to retrieve the data about it's parents object. The class looks like this;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item", schema = "tmp", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "item_id"), @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "item_name")})
public class Item implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private Integer itemId;
  private String itemName;
  private String itemDescription;
  private Item itemParent;
  private boolean isEndItem;
  private List<Item> childrenItems;


  public Item() {}

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "item_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
  public Integer getItemId() {
    return itemId;
  }

  public void setItemId(final Integer itemId) {
    this.itemId = itemId;
  }

  @Column(name = "item_name", unique = true, nullable = false)
  public String getItemName() {
    return itemName;
  }

  public void setItemName(final String itemName) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
  }

  @Column(name = "item_description", unique = false, nullable = false)
  public String getItemDescription() {
    return itemDescription;
  }

  public void setItemDescription(final String itemDescription) {
    this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
  }

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonManagedReference(value = "item-item")
  @JoinColumn(name="item_parentid")
  public Item getParentItem() {
    return this.itemParent;
  }

  public void setParentItem(final Item itemParent){
    this.itemParent = itemParent;
  }

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="childrenItems", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonBackReference(value = "item-item")
  public List<Item> getChildrenItems(){
    return this.childrenItems;
  }

  public void setChildrenItems(final List<Item> childrenItems){
    this.childrenItems = childrenItems;
  }

  @Column(name = "item_isendproduct", unique = false, nullable = false)
  public boolean isEndItem() {
    return isEndItem;
  }

  public void setEndItem(final boolean isEndItem) {
    this.isEndItem = isEndItem;
  }
}
```

In my database, testing data is saved in this hierarchy:

**Entry > Salad > House Salad**

```
[  
   {  
      "itemId":1,
      "itemName":"Entry",
      "itemDescription":"Entry Menu",
      "endItem":false,
      "parentItem":null
   },
   {  
      "itemId":2,
      "itemName":"Salad",
      "itemDescription":"Salad Menu",
      "endItem":false,
      "parentItem":{  
         "itemId":1,
         "itemName":"Entry",
         "itemDescription":"Entry Menu",
         "endItem":false,
         "parentItem":null
      }
   },
   {  
      "itemId":3,
      "itemName":"House Salad",
      "itemDescription":"House Salad",
      "endItem":true,
      "parentItem":{  
         "itemId":2,
         "itemName":"Salad",
         "itemDescription":"Salad Menu",
         "endItem":false,
         "parentItem":{  
            "itemId":1,
            "itemName":"Entry",
            "itemDescription":"Entry Menu",
            "endItem":false,
            "parentItem":null
         }
      }
   }
]
```

But I don't want to know the information about the parent's parent object.
Is there any annotations that I can use to achieve this?

Thank in advance

Comment: You should add `parentItemId` instead of the entire parent object. So, *each* item has a reference to its parent via id.

Comment: getting this error, "@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.tmp.model.Item.parentItemId references an unknown entity: java.lang.Integer"

Comment: @Yogesh's advice is Bad Advice for JPA, the whole point of which is to manage that. Generally, you'll want to decouple your JSON representation from the actual stored format--as a quick hack, though, you can use something like `@JsonIdentityInfo` on the relationship fields.

Comment: @chrylis is there any example that I can take a look?

Comment: your mapping is wrong. If you have a 1-N and specify a _mappedBy_ it should be the field in the element class that points back to this class. In the case of a 1-N the _mappedBy_ specifies the N-1 field at the other side. Yours doesnt